# CIUnit test result not being displayed when loading database in model

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, codeigniter-2

I am trying to get CIUnit working with my Fedora 17 64-bit machine.
While following [this](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/Kenji_s/20120117/1326763908) tutorial with my existing code, I encountered odd behaviour as shown below.

```
[root@fedora tests]# phpunit --debug
PHPUnit 3.7.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from /test_app/tests/phpunit.xml
Starting test 'ManagerModelTest::testNumServers'.
[root@fedora tests]#
```

And then, nothing happens. I tested exact same code on windows 7, and it worked fine (displayed number of tests asserted and failed). But when I tried on fedora, no result was displayed. Followings are my model and test classes.

```
class Manager_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database('agreements');
    }
}

class ManagerModelTest extends CIUnit_TestCase
{
    private $mm;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->CI->load->model('manager_model');
        $this->mm = $this->CI->manager_model;
    }

    public function testNumServers()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(FALSE);
    }
}
```

I am not even using any of model functions in the test. However, if I comment out `$this->load->database('agreements');` in model, it works fine. I checked log file, but found no error message. Why is this happening on Fedora machine, and not on Windows 7?

Comment: It turned out that my php-cli did not have mysql.ini loaded, and therefore not supporting `mysql_connect()`. After installing php-mysql, it seems to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my php-cli did not have mysql.ini loaded, and therefore not supporting `mysql_connect()`. After installing php-mysql, it seems to be working.